# Probability Theory: Cramer Transform Issue and deviation probabilities theory.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\xi$ be random variable with probability distribution $F_\xi$.

Let $\tilde\xi$ be random variable with probability distribution $\tilde F_\xi$

$I_{\xi}^t(x) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^x e^{ts}dF_\xi(ds)$

$\tilde F_\xi (x) = \frac{I_{\xi}^t(x)}{I_{\xi}^t(+\infty)}$

Then, we can say, that we use Cramer transform with $\xi$ variable.

Ok, Cramer transform we can use with all distributions.

But in **deviation probabilities theory** Cramer transform uses very often.

Question, related to **deviation probabilities theory**:
Can anybody explain this tip: Is it needed to approximate discrete probability distribution with continuous probability distributions? For which reason?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `Is it needed to approximate...`

Comment: Then the answer is NO, there is no direct relationship between LD theory and the approximation of discrete probability distribution by continuous probability distributions. What makes you think there could be some?